# Connect websocketpp to ip v4 and v6 on FreeBSD

Tags: c++, c++11, websocket, freebsd

I modified the 'extended connection storage'-example at http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/manual/common-patterns/storing-connection-specificsession-information and it's working on OS X (el capitan). When I cloned the program to FreeBSD I could not connect to the websocket. It turns out that it listens only to v6 on FreeBSD. And v4 plus v6 on OS X. I overloaded listen() as suggested by the documentation to use v4 so I could test it.

Overloading to v4 does not seem to be very future-proof. How can I make the program listen to both v4 and v6 on FreeBSD?

I changed the program to

```
void run(uint16_t port) {
    m_server.listen(websocketpp::lib::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port);
    m_server.start_accept();
    m_server.run();
}
```

On OS X it is

```
m_server.listen(port);
```